# Why m*(E) <= m*(En) if E = union of(En)?

Tags: real-analysis

I encountered a proof for this theorem:

Assume $\cup En = E$ and m*(E) is the outer measure of E, then m*(E) <= $\sum m*(En) $.

Let $\epsilon$ > 0. The proof uses open intervals {Ik,n} and says that for each n, we can find a group of {Ik,n} such that En $\subset Ik,n$.

What I understand is that {Ik,n} are some intervals with increasing radius $\mathcal n$ that cover En, If that is right then how the next statement in the proof can be true?

The statement is that $\sum |Ik,n| <= m*(En) + \epsilon/2^n $ where |Ik,n| is the length of the Ik,n

If En $\subset $ Ik,n, how can the sum be right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of outer measure $m^*(E_n)$ is the supremum of $\{ \sum_k |I_{k,n}| : \bigcup_k I_{k,n}$ covers $E_n \}$.

So for any positive $\epsilon$, we can find some set of intervals $\{ I_{k,n} \}$ such that $\sum_k |I_{k,n}| : \bigcup_k I_{k,n} \le m^*(E_n) + \epsilon$.

Now, $\epsilon / 2^k$ is positive, so we can find a similar set of intervals that satisfies the inequality for $\epsilon / 2^k$ in the place of $\epsilon$.